# Whatsapp Business API Registration - Acquire certificate from whatsapp buiness manager

Tags: facebook, certificate, whatsapp, cacerts

Installed whatasppp Business api followed the link  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/installation

Logged into https://localhost:9090/

For registration, it requires a phone number and a certificate.

[image: Registration]

Setup the Whatsapp Business APP for phone number then added the number in  Facebook business manager.

However, couldn't acquire the cerificate to complete the registration.
There are instructions in the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/account
but couldn't follow it, there is no settings tab or whatsapp manager button to acquire the certificate as mentioned in 3rd point.

1. Go to the Business Settings in your Facebook Business Manager.
2. Click on WhatsApp Accounts under the Accounts menu, then select your WhatsApp Account from the WhatsApp Accounts list, if it isn't already highlighted.
3. Go to the Settings tab, and click the WhatsApp Manager button.
4. Under the Phone Numbers tab, you should see your phone numbers listed. Click the View button of the phone number you want the certificate for.

[image: Business Manager]

Useful Links

Embedded

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2640149499569241

Direct

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started

Verification

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gtj82ugi-bI

Comment: i'm having same issue .did you find a solution ?

Comment: @noboundaries I have the same concern with you. How did you able to solved this? Thank you.

Comment: @noboundaries  I am also having the same issue. Did you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking at on Facebook Business Manager is the WhatsApp account for your WhatsApp Business App. This is the 'WhatsApp for Business' app account that you can download from Google Playstore or Apple AppStore. In order for you to create and use WhatsApp Business API account, you need to create an api account. You can reach a Business Solution Provider to help you setup an account. More details can be found [here](https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api/?lang=fb) on WhatsApp's official page.

[Here](https://www.facebook.com/business/partner-directory/search?platforms=whatsapp&solution_type=messaging) is the list of BSPs provided on their website.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I have the same concern. Right now we want to integrate hte WhatsaApp Business API.

Comment: There are two types of WhatsApp Business options available: 1. WhatsApp Business App on iPhone/Android play stores 2. WhatsApp Business API. The second option is available through a BSP only. What you're looking at when the account says WhatsApp Business App is the first option.
In order to create 2 option, you need to work with BSPs, I have provided a list in the answer above.

Comment: What if our company wants to be a Business Solution Provider? So our company can able to create whatsapp account for our clients? Will this be possible?

Comment: @Jearson Please share the information if you know the whole procedure to be BSP of WhatsApp Business API and the development path for the same.