# Finishing Whatsapp Business API Setup

Tags: facebook, certificate, whatsapp

I came from a similar state in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64360536/whatsapp-business-api-registration-acquire-certificate-from-whatsapp-buiness-m).

My objective is to reply to interested customers via whatsapp messages. I'll use a very special setup, so I'll be using the API.

Reasons:

- With not to pay anyone other than container hosts
- Solution with custom API
- Customer doesn't like any extra costs

Just like user *noboundaries*, I see the numbers, but I cant get the certificate
User *Navjot Singh* has explained I need to create a "business api account"

I tried just that, put out all my contacts and stuff, in [this site](https://www.facebook.com/business/m/whatsapp/business-api).
They did respond yes, but only with pointless instructions, since **I wish not** to contract any messaging providers. I had taken a look at it, but they charge a very expensive price beyond the  $0.005 whatsapp will charge. Also, the solution I'm creating requires messages to be sent programatically, and the partners don't seem to provide the correct solution.

So, I wish to skip into using the api. I followed the appropriate guides:

- [Getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/getting-started)
- [Phone Number](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/phone-number)

I already got some things done:

- two phone numbers (one of them for testing) with whatsapp business;
- company has been verified, with domain
- have business management account
- local environment with docker

I can access the local environment and I have set an user account and the admin acount. I can log into those via the API, since postman can ignore certificates, but in order to proceed I really feel like I need that certificate.

So to sim up I guess I need help creating the whatsapp business account for my customer. Any advice?
Also i'd appreciate any other helpful insight or feedback. I really feel lost and I don't see a place where I can talk to people trying to do the same thing, or doing this is much of a madness after all?

thanks for getting to read until here, and I apologize for my non natural, almost broken English.

Answer (score 0):

About the subject at hand, yesterday I dwelt deep into the rabbit hole.
For most companies, you actually are **forced** to work with a provider, such as Twilio or Messagebird. They act as intermediary between the Facebook business and the WhatsApp Business API.

Some of they offer messaging separated from WhatsApp API setup I still need to take a look into it, but for those who are trying to set up WhatsApp Business API on their own, it seems as of November 2020 it's not possible.

Please check out:

- [respond.io's guide](https://respond.io/blog/whatsapp-business-api/)
- [blog post from take.net](https://take.net/blog/whatsapp/verificacao-de-contas-no-whatsapp-requisitos) **PT-BR** (google translate didn't like me trying to translate this to English)